# Simulating post hoc power for multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, simulation, statistical-power

I have a null result for a negative binomial regression model and I would like to give evidence that my sample is large enough to detect even small effects.

I've found a few online calculators for power analysis, but I'd prefer to use simulation. I haven't been able to find many resources about how to do this.

Comment: Your sample size was not enough to detect your effect, so your power is zero. See Lenth (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fbfb/cab4b59e54c6a3ed39ba3656f35ef86c5ee3.pdf) for a "grand unified formula" for posthoc power. For an alternative, you can try "design analysis" https://andrewgelman.com/2017/03/03/yes-makes-sense-design-analysis-power-calculations-data-collected/

Answer (score 1):

For your given sample size and the observed effect size your power was <50%, no need for simulation. If that's a meaningful effect size,  the study was under-powered.

If that is not the case and the confidence intervals exclude a meaningful effect size,  then you have a pretty good argument that the study had provided a pretty clear answer.

What's the particular problem with simulating? Simulate your drop out/ censoring process, condition on the simulated drop out times,  then either simulate straight from a negative binomial, or simulate as a Gamma-Poisson mixture (useful if you also have a baseline period and need to capture the within subject correlation for that). Then apply your analysis model to each simulated dataset.

Comment: For your second statement, the pretty clear answer is that there is no effect?